# What are the android SDK platform packages for?

Tags: android

What are the Android SDK platform packages for?

Do I need to download corresponding platform for every API level I'm targeting?

Comment: IIRC, you don't have to download for every single one you're targeting, but you have to download the one that's compiled against (`compileSdk`)

Comment: @Zoe What does "compiled against" mean in this case?

Comment: There is documentation about supporting different API levels. Read: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: @Ale-Jandra as I mentioned in the parenthesis (maybe not clearly enough, sorry 'bout that), the version defined by `compileSdkVersion` in build.gradle. If you set it to 23, you need the SDK platform package for API 23.

Comment: Just as you need a Java Development Kit to program in Java, you need an Android Software Development Kit to program for Android. Various Java verisons exist. Android upgrades more frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minSdkVersion` is the minimum API version your app is compatible with. You don't need to download anything according to this value. If you set a value of, say, 21 (Marshmallow) your app *won't run* on a device with android version 19 (KitKat).

`targetSdkVersion` is used to detect the highest sdk version your app is compatible with, it indicates forward-compatibility. The difference here is that if you set a target version of, say, 21 your app *will run* on a device with android 23. It can just be used by a future version of Android to know if there might be some new feature that your app won't support. Google Play policy has been recently updated so that you will be forced to use a recent API version as your target, read [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html).

`compileSdkVersion` is the version of the Android SDK you use when compiling your app. You have to download that version of the SDK in order to compile your app and use classes from that version of the SDK. For instance, you might want to use the class `Context`, and call the method `getColor(int)`, the version 23 of the SDK has it so you can use it in your code. If you're using version 21 though, the method is not there so you can't call it in your app. You see here that `minSdkVersion` is also useful because you might want to use this method, but it's been introduced only in version 23 and since you have a min SDK 21 you will get a warning at compile time.

The build tools are used to compile your app and you should be updating them to latest version regardless of the aforementioned values. I think with recent versions of the Android gradle plugin you don't need to set this value anymore, it will be handled automagically.

To sum up, you only need to download the SDK of the API version you're compiling against, that is, `compileSdkVersion`.

About the meaning of "compile against", when you write an app you compile your code and pack it into an apk, the apk is then deployed to a device. In your code you use classes from the Android SDK (e.g. `Context`) but the code for those classes is not included in the apk, it is provided from the OS of the device on which your app will run. If you want to compile a class that is using those SDK classes, you have to "show" those SDK classes to the compiler so that it can then compile your own classes.

Answer (score -1):

When you set `android:minSdkVersion` it means that you want to use the benefits and development tools of that version (also the users below that `minSdkVersion` can not use your application). So you have to download the SDK which supports your tools and needs for that minimum version.

also if you have set `android:targetSdkVersion` it means that you have tested your application against that version. So obviously you need to download the required tools for testing that version too. If you don't set `android:targetSdkVersion` it will be equal to `minSdkVersion` by default.

**Footnote:** using the latest version of SDK (as compileSdkVersion) gives you the power of using latest tools and platforms benefits. The development software will warn you if you use a tool which is not supported by `targeted` or `minSdkVersion` of your users.

Comment: _you have to download at least one SDK which supports your tools and needs for that minimum version (any version equal or higher)_  -
 this is wrong, you have to download the SDK for the API level you're compiling against. Not at least one, not equal or higher min sdk version.